# Angular is not binding data

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

here is my index.html and safeCtrl.js controller. I am trying to using angularJS to implement the angular smart table :[http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/][1] .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>     
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="smart-table.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="lrInfiniteScrollPlugin.js"></script>

    <div ng-controller="safecCtrl">

        <button type="button" ng-click="addRandomItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
            </i> Add random item
        </button>

        <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
                    <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
                    <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
                    <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" /></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
                    <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" ng-click="removeItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
                            </i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>


</body>
</html>



    app.controller('safeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var firstnames = ['Laurent', 'Blandine', 'Olivier', 'Max'];
    var lastnames = ['Renard', 'Faivre', 'Frere', 'Eponge'];
    var dates = ['1987-05-21', '1987-04-25', '1955-08-27', '1966-06-06'];
    var id = 1;

    function generateRandomItem(id) {

        var firstname = firstnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        var lastname = lastnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        var birthdate = dates[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        var balance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);

        return {
            id: id,
            firstName: firstname,
            lastName: lastname,
            birthDate: new Date(birthdate),
            balance: balance
        }
    }

    $scope.rowCollection = [];

    for (id; id < 5; id++) {
        $scope.rowCollection.push(generateRandomItem(id));
    }

    //add to the real data holder
    $scope.addRandomItem = function addRandomItem() {
        $scope.rowCollection.push(generateRandomItem(id));
        id++;
    };

    //remove to the real data holder
    $scope.removeItem = function removeItem(row) {
        var index = $scope.rowCollection.indexOf(row);
        if (index !== -1) {
            $scope.rowCollection.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I was using visual studio 2017. Right now the page is weird because the data is not binding. Can anyone help me with this? I am really confusing...Thanks.

Comment: oops, the link is [smart table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating over the wrong collection. It should be rowCollection and not displayedCollection.